# Group array of JSON object by specific key and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to group an array of JSON objects by the `id_commande` attribute and remove any duplicates.
I'm really confused on how I should approach this problem without the use of a library (I've heard of lodash). If possible I would like to do this **in plain javascript**.

```js
let listeCommandes = [
                 {
                    id_commande: 18,
                    date: "2020-12-07",
                    etat: "en traitement",
                    nom: "Tom Kha Gai",
                    prix_total: 16.68,
                    quanitite: 1,
                },
                {
                    id_commande: 18,
                    date: "2020-12-07",
                    etat: "en traitement",
                    nom: "Tom Yum Talai",
                    prix_total: 16.68,
                    quanitite: 1,
                },
                {
                    id_commande: 19,
                    date: "2020-12-07",
                    etat: "en traitement",
                    nom: "Tom Yum Gai",
                    prix_total: 16.1,
                    quanitite: 1,
                },
                {
                    id_commande: 19,
                    date: "2020-12-07",
                    etat: "en traitement",
                    nom: "Tom Yum Tai",
                    prix_total: 16.1,
                    quanitite: 1,
                }
            ];
```

Expected output is :

```js
let join = [{
                        id_commande: 18,
                        date: "2020-12-07",
                        etat: "en traitement",
                        plats: [{
                                nom: "Tom Kha Gai",
                                quantite: 1
                            },
                            {
                                nom: "Tom Yum Talai",
                                quantite: 1
                            }
                        ],
                        prix_total: 16.68
                    },
                    {
                        id_commande: 19,
                        date: "2020-12-07",
                        etat: "en traitement",
                        plats: [{
                                nom: "Tom Yum Gai",
                                quantite: 1
                            },
                            {
                                nom: "Tom Yum Tai",
                                quantite: 1
                            }
                        ],
                        prix_total: 16.1
                    },
                ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` function to handle this.

```js
let listeCommandes = [
    {
        id_commande: 18,
        date: "2020-12-07",
        etat: "en traitement",
        nom: "Tom Kha Gai",
        prix_total: 16.68,
        quanitite: 1,
    },
    {
        id_commande: 18,
        date: "2020-12-07",
        etat: "en traitement",
        nom: "Tom Yum Talai",
        prix_total: 16.68,
        quanitite: 1,
    },
    {
        id_commande: 19,
        date: "2020-12-07",
        etat: "en traitement",
        nom: "Tom Yum Gai",
        prix_total: 16.1,
        quanitite: 1,
    },
    {
        id_commande: 19,
        date: "2020-12-07",
        etat: "en traitement",
        nom: "Tom Yum Tai",
        prix_total: 16.1,
        quanitite: 1,
    }
];

const result = listeCommandes.reduce((res, current) => {
    // see if id is already in the output
    const result = res.find(e => e.id_commande === current.id_commande);
    if (result) {
        // if the id is there update the plats with the new info
        result.plats = [...result.plats, { nom: current.nom, quanitite: current.quanitite }]
        return res
    } else {
        // if the id isn't there, add a new object.
        return [...res, {
            id_commande: current.id_commande,
            date: current.date,
            etat: current.etat,
            plats: [{
                nom: current.nom,
                quantite: current.quanitite
            }],
            prix_total: current.prix_total
        }]
    }
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer / comments !
 I'll read into this reduce function to understand your code more.

Comment: No problem, `res` is the return value of the function on the previous element and `current` is the current item you are on, it runs the function on each item in the array to build the final returned value. I passed the `[]` after the function as the initial `res` value to start with an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var listeCommandes = [
                 {
                    id_commande: 18,
                    date: "2020-12-07",
                    etat: "en traitement",
                    nom: "Tom Kha Gai",
                    prix_total: 16.68,
                    quanitite: 1,
                },
                {
                    id_commande: 18,
                    date: "2020-12-07",
                    etat: "en traitement",
                    nom: "Tom Yum Talai",
                    prix_total: 16.68,
                    quanitite: 1,
                },
                {
                    id_commande: 19,
                    date: "2020-12-07",
                    etat: "en traitement",
                    nom: "Tom Yum Gai",
                    prix_total: 16.1,
                    quanitite: 1,
                },
                {
                    id_commande: 19,
                    date: "2020-12-07",
                    etat: "en traitement",
                    nom: "Tom Yum Tai",
                    prix_total: 16.1,
                    quanitite: 1,
                }
            ];
        grouped = function (listeCommandes) {
        var r = [];
        listeCommandes.forEach(function (a) {
            var key = a.id_commande + '|' + a.date+ '|' + a.etat;
            if (!this[key]) {
                this[key] = { id_commande: a.id_commande, date: a.date, etat: a.etat, plats: [] };
                r.push(this[key]);
            }
            this[key].plats.push({nom : a.nom, quanitite : a.quanitite});

        }, {});
        return r;
    }(listeCommandes);    
           
           document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```